# The Loop Which is Based On Keyboard Input Condition

Tags: java

```
class Example2{
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException {
            int i;
            System.out.println("Press S to Stop!");
            for(i=0 ; (char) System.in.read() != 'S' ; i++){
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought that it will display the numbers like this:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7.... Till I press the S. But it didn't show anything except first println expression.Why this occurs?

Comment: it works.. it's just that you have to press *Enter* for every iteration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for-loop works in the following way:

```
for(initialization; termination; increment) statement
```

See [java nutsandbolts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

`initialization` runs before the first run of `statement`, `increment` after ever run and `termination` is evaluated before every run of `statement`.

In your example `termination` is `(char) System.in.read() != 'S'`, which means in every repetition, the program reads another character from `System.in`. Now the buffer of `System.in` doesn't contain any characters and thus the program will wait for the user to input anything it can process. This will happen for every repetition of the loop.

So your program waits for the user to input anything and won't terminate until that happens.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you **wait and read** the input at every iteration. Thus, it just waits for your keyboard input every time..

Instead:

1. You could loop **as long as there are no character in the input stream** : `System.in.available()`.
2. Then, you'd **only read the input when a character as been typed**: `System.in.read();`:

---

Complete code:

```
int i=0;
System.out.println("Press S to Stop!");
char car = ' ';
while (car != 'S') {
    while (System.in.available() == 0) {
        System.out.print(i++ + " ");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    car = (char) System.in.read();
}
```

I've added `Thread.sleep(1000);` because it goes too fast... remove it, you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The program waits for an input,

If you want it to run until you write "S" you can use threads

Something like this would work:

```
class MainClass{

     static boolean toStop;

     public static void main(String args[])
         throws java.io.IOException {
            toStop = false;
            thread R1 = new thread("ThreadName");
            R1.start();
            int i = 0;
            while(!toStop){
                System.out.print(i+" ");
                i++;
            }
         }
}

class thread implements  Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    thread( String name) {
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      char input;
        try {
            System.out.println("Press S to Stop!");
            input = (char) System.in.read();
            while(input != 'S'){
                input = (char) System.in.read();
            }
            MainClass.toStop = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void start () {
              System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
              if (t == null) {
                 t = new Thread (this, threadName);
                 t.start ();
              }
    }
}
```